# Laravel can't pass value to controller after submitting to database

Tags: php, laravel

After submitting to the database and redirecting/reloading the page I get the error `Trying to get property 'stockcount1' of non-object`. I know it has to do with the product id not being properly passed back but I'm having trouble finding a fix.

##### `show.blade.php`

```html
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview', $data['product']->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    {{-- {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }} --}}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::textarea('description', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Write your message']) }}
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('rating', 'Rating') }}
        {{ Form::select('rating', ['1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'], '1') }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

##### `web.php`

```php
Route::get('/addreview/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@show');
Route::post('/addreview/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview');

Route::get('/products/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@show');
```

##### `pagescontroller.php`

```php
public function addreview(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'description' => 'required',
        'rating' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    $review =  new Review;

    $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
    $review->reviewerid = auth()->user()->id;
    $review->productid = $id;
    $review->description = $request->input('description');

    $review->save();

    $product = Product::find($id);
    $reviews = DB::table('reviews')->where('productid', '=', $id)->paginate(10);
    $sum = $product->stockcount1 + $product->stockcount2 + $product->stockcount3;

    $data = array();
    $data['product'] = $product;
    $data['stocktotal'] = $sum;
    $data['reviews'] = $reviews;
    $data['id'] = $id;

    return redirect('/products/{$id}')->with('success', 'Review submitted')->with(compact('data'));
    //return view('products.show')->with('success', 'Review submitted')->with(compact("data"));
}
```

##### `productscontroller.php`

```php
$product = Product::find($id);
Log::info(print_r($id, true));

$reviews = DB::table('reviews')->where('productid', '=', $id)->paginate(10);
$sum = $product->stockcount1 + $product->stockcount2 + $product->stockcount3;

$data = array();
$data['product'] = $product;
$data['stocktotal'] = $sum;
$data['reviews'] = $reviews;
$data['id'] = $id;

return view('products.show')->with(compact('data'));
```

Comment: `redirect('/products/{$id}')` change that single quote into double quote or to `redirect('/products/'.$id)`. Or use named routes. Also you could use some cleaning on your code..remove redundant stuff..

Comment: worked like a charm. It also fixed another bug I was having too, thanks. And I know the code isn't the best looking, I normally code in swift and java so I wanted to get this working before I refactored it.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change `redirect('/products/{$id}')` to `redirect('/products/'.$id)`.

Thanks to [@user3532758](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3532758/user3532758)